# nodejs azure createBlockBlobFromLocalFile timeout

Tags: node.js, azure, upload, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload an mp4 video file to Azure. I am working with Node.js.

If the file is small it works fine, but if it is big (more than 10 mb) it gives me this error:

ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

this is the function I use:

```
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(container, file.name, file.path, options,
                    function (error, result, response) {
                        try {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log('***** ERROR file NOT uploaded! ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                                reject(error);
                            }
                            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                                reject({error: 'Failed to create blob.'});
                            }
                            console.log('***** createBlockBlobFromLocalFile FILE uploaded! ');
                            resolve();
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log('***** ERROR file NOT uploaded! ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    })
```

Please can someone help me?

Thank you so much. Emi

Comment: Can you share the complete code? I am interested in seeing how you're creating `blobService` and defining `options`.

Comment: I changed
createBlockBlobFromLocalFile
 by createBlockBlobFromText and it's working OK!

Comment: Awesome! However please ensure that the contents of the file are OK. In my experience uploading binary content using `createBlockBlobFromText` corrupts the file contents.

Comment: ups!
I will pay attention. Thank you

Comment: You were right, the files were not uploaded completely.
I will continue to investigate why I get the error ESOCKETTIMEDOUT with createBlockBlobFromLocalFile
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The socket timeout usually happens when network is poor or network in heavy usage. Try to add retry filter on client library side.

Refer : https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter.html

Refer the similar discussion over the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/401) .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sandeep br I applied retry filter on client library side and it worked with a file of 116 MB.

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(
        azureContainer.Credentials.storageAccount,
        azureContainer.Credentials.accessKey
        ).withFilter(retryOperations);
```

Thank you very much !